# why is unsupervised learning said to be learning probability distribution?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, unsupervised-learning

In the book **Deep Learning** by Ian Goodfellow et al., it is mentioned that

> unsupervised learning involves observing several examples
> of a random vector x, and attempting to implicitly or explicitly learn the probability distribution p(x)

However when I think about the typical unsupervised algorithms such as clustering and anomaly detection, I fail to understand why such algorithms are learning $p(x)$. For example in anomaly detection, is it not more accurate to say that it is learning $p(Y|X)$ where Y = 1 if the data is an anomaly and 0 otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example in anomaly detection, is it not more accurate to say that it is learning $p(Y|X)$ where Y = 1 if the data is an anomaly and 0 otherwise?

If that was the case, how would this differ from classification? In anomaly detection you don't have labels, or have insufficient labels to treat this as classification. In such a case, you don't observe $Y$ so cannot learn $p(Y|X)$ from the data. Instead, you observe only $X$ and can learn $p(X)$, so you could make judgements like "$x'$ is not alike what we observed for $X$" (anomaly), or "$x'$ looks like the data $X$ that we previously observed". We can think of those as of probabilistic statements that $\Pr(X = x')$ is small. The models themselves can either be probabilistic and return the predictions in terms of probabilities or can do this indirectly by telling us what is the distance between $x'$ and the rest of the data. In each case, the model that is able to tell us things like this needs to have a notion of the underlying probability distribution, hence we say it learned to approximate the distribution.